# Comma separated string not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

problem

- I need the return value from xhr request to be like 1,2,3
- so that I can append comma separated value in textbox.
- I tried but its only appending like 1, only.

input data:

9037566,

9037579,

9037577,

9030724,

9019686,

but  output data should be like for example

1,2,3,4,5

json data as input

```
{ "keyword_search":
  {"data":
    [
      {"JOB_NO":"9037566"},
      {"JOB_NO":"9037579"},
      {"JOB_NO":"9037577"},
       {"JOB_NO":"9030724"},
           {"JOB_NO":"9019686"}
         ]}}
```

js code i tried with

```
           $.ajax({
           url: root_url + 'mylogs/keyword',
           cache: false,
           type: "POST",
           data: {'data': keyword},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (html) {
                var keyword=html.keyword_search.data;
                $.each(keyword, function (key, value){
                    console.log(value.JOB_NO.split(',')+',');
```

- but when I tried to append $("#id").val(value.JOB_NO.split(',')+',');
- it only appending like

  ```
  9037566,
  ```
- i help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `console.log()` for each iteration of the loop, and therefore you will get a seperate output for each piece of data.

Change the following:

```
       success: function (html) {
            var keyword=html.keyword_search.data;
            $.each(keyword, function (key, value){
                console.log(value.JOB_NO.split(',')+',');
```

To:

```
       success: function (html) {
            var keyword=html.keyword_search.data;
            var jobNos = keyword.map(function(i){
                 return i.JOB_NO;
            });
            console.log(jobNos.join(","));
```

---

Simplified example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lscewr1v/